# What type of variable am I passing to the API controller while uploading the file?

Tags: c#

Here is the complete code on how to send emails WITH ATTACHMENTS via API.
I had problem with deleting the file after sending it to smtp server. And I couldn't figure out how to pass additional data along with the files. 
This article helped https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2
Thanks you for help.

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("to", "g@gmail.com");
    formData.append("subject", "Yo man");
    formData.append("body", "I'm happy");
    formData.append("file[]", $('#fileToAttach')[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: "/api/emailwithattachment",
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
})


    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/emailwithattachment")]
    public async Task<string> UploadFile()
    {

    var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    var root = ctx.Server
        .MapPath("~/UploadedFiles");
    var provider =
        new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    await Request.Content
        .ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    var To = "";
    var Subject = "";
    var Body = "";

    foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
    {
        foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
        {
            if (key == "to")
                To = val;
            if (key == "subject")
                Subject = val;
            if (key == "body")
                Body = val;
        }
    }

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    mail.From = new MailAddress("g@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add(To);
    mail.Subject = Subject;
    mail.Body = Body;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("g@gmail.com", "password");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;


    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;

    List<string> filePaths = new List<string>();

    foreach (var file in provider.FileData)
    {
        var fileName = "CONF " + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm-ss") + ".pdf";

        var localFileName = file.LocalFileName;
        var filePath = Path.Combine(root, fileName);
        File.Move(localFileName, filePath);

        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(filePath);
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        filePaths.Add(filePath);


    }

    SmtpServer.Send(mail);

    mail.Dispose();/////Here was the problem

    foreach (var file in filePaths)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
            File.Delete(file);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return e.Message;
        }
    }
    return "success";
}
```

Comment: a) Please provide a [mcve]. b) Disable your antivirus.

Comment: It seems likely that whatever you're doing in the "send files as attachments" part is the culprit. You need to include a *complete* minimal example.

Comment: Herohtar, you were right. The "email" was using my file. I disposed of it and now everything works. Thank you.

Answer (score -4):

You need to figure out wich other process is using the file. And then close the process, or at least get it to release the file. However the 90% case for this exception, is that you opened the file in this programm before and *did not properly release it*.

File and Networking classes involve unmanaged resources - OS Level handles. Their classes are marked as Disposeable. They need to be properly disposed off - after use - to properly release those unmanaged resources. My rule for Disposeable classes of all shapes and forms is: "Create. Use. Dispose. All in the same piece of code, ideally using a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)."

Comment: How can I use "using" in this particular case?

Comment: @kostinalex `mail.Dispose();` is not a reliable way to dispose of it. A return, exception or other jump might "skip over" it. You can not skip over the Disposing that comes from a using block. If you jump out, it is still reliably executed. Unreliable disposing does not mater. That is the purpose of the using block - 100% **RELIABLE** Disposing.